# condition in for loop with if operator

Tags: c++, c, scope

basically I have this function repeat I understand what it does, what I don't understand is the this part of the condition in the for loop `v ? sizeof(g) / 8 : 0`, if someone could explain it me I would appreciate a lot because I don't get what it does.

program:

```
char g[1024];
double *repeat(double *v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (v ? sizeof(g) / 8 : 0); i++)
    {
        if (v[i] > 2 * i)
            v[i] = i;
        else
            v[i] = 0;
    }
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    double *t;
    *t = 2.0;
    t = repeat(t);
    printf("Numero: %f\n",*t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `double *t; *t = 2.0;` exhibits undefined behavior by way of dereferencing uninitialized pointer `t`

Comment: My guess is, `v` is meant to point to `g` or to some array of the same size. But in your example, it doesn't point to anything valid at all.

Comment: You say you understand what `repeat` does. I don't. So, what is it supposed to do?

Comment: `(v ? sizeof(g) / 8 : 0)` says: if `v` is null, don't run the loop at all, just return null. Otherwise, assume `v` points to an array of `sizeof(g) / 8` elements. It's too clever by half.

Comment: @Martimc The code does not make a sense. So there is nothing to discuss.

Comment: @Martimc Especially this code snippet     double *t;
    *t = 2.0; or this code snippet        if (v[i] > 2 * i)
            v[i] = i;. There is neither sense in this code. A very silly code with numerous bugs.

Comment: @Martimc Pay attention to that in any case the conditional operator in the condition of the for loop makes the code unclear. As it was pointed to it is much better to use an if statement before the for loop that checks whether the pointer is a null pointer or not. And I removed the down-vote.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat obscure code, as illustrated by the number of incorrect attempts at answers. The key here is that the `?:` operator makes an **expression**, that is, it's code that produces a **value**. So, first look at the **value** of the expression:

```
(v ? sizeof(g) / 8 : 0)
```

where `v` is a pointer. When a pointer is used in a context that expects a boolean value, the value is `true` if the pointer is not a null pointer, and `false` if it is. So, you could think of this expression as

```
(v != nullptr ? sizeof(g) / 8 : 0)
```

This expression is the upper bound of the `for` loop. The loop will execute for as long as `i < (v ? sizeof(g) / 8 : 0)` is true. So, if `v` is a null pointer, the condition is `i < 0`, which is false, and the body of the loop will not be run. If `v` is not a null pointer, the condition is `i < sizeof(g)/8`, and the body of the loop will be run as many times as whatever that value is.

Answer (score 0):

If v is **true**, then sizeof(g) / 8 gets executed. If v is false, then 0 gets executed

Comment: `v` is a pointer, not a boolean.

Comment: thats why i get even more confused

Comment: You can also say "if v exists", then sizeof(g)/8 gets executed @Martimc

Comment: @aflo7 -- `v` exists; it's the name of the function argument. The test is whether the **value** of `v` is `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

If the input parameter `v` is not `NULL`, then we compare `i` to the result of `sizeof(g) / 8` (64 in this particular case); otherwise we compare `i` to `0`.

The following code would be equivalent (and probably a little easier to understand):

```
int count = 0;
if ( v )
  count = sizeof g / 8; 

for ( int i = 1; i < count; i++ ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say in a comment you are confused because `v` is a pointer, not a boolean — and yet is used in a condition:

Since the beginning of C++ there is a well-defined automatic conversion of pointers to booleans which is defined exactly for this use case of testing whether a pointer is null instead of the wordy `if(p != 0 )`. The latter is more complicated hence more error prone:

- OK, we compare against a null pointer (in C++ a literal zero was the only null pointer literal before the introduction of `nullptr`).
- OK, we test for inequality.
- OK, two negations (null pointer and inequality) make for a positive: Is the pointer there? I think that's what it is. I'm tired. Let's be sure and play it through in our minds. I have a valid pointer. It is not equal to `0`. Inequality therefore returns false. The false result indicates it's a valid pointer. I think this is what I wanted, right? Where was I?

Instead , you simply write `if(p)`. no comparison, no double logic inversion, it couldn't be simpler: If the pointer is there, do something with it  ;-).

Answer (score -1):

i < (v ? sizeof(g) / 8 : 0)

This is the equivalent of saying this shorthand:

```
if(v){
  i < sizeof(g)/8;
}else{
  i < 0;
}
```

Comment: While that's sort of true about the except that's quoted in the answer, it's not helpful, because the first one is an **expression**, and the second is not. The **value** of the expression matters, because that's what determines the upper bound of the `for` loop in the question.